# Using iptables to block ALL outgoing traffic from one NIC?

Tags: linux, iptables, router, linux-networking

I must pretty bad at Googling as this seems like a very basic question but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere... and `man iptables` is a very long read!

I have two NICs - eth0 and eth1 - on a linux box and I want to block ALL outbound traffic (TCP and UDP across all ports) from one of the NICs, so that no traffic makes its way back up to the router.

What is the command for this? I have only seen examples with specific ports.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With `iptables -A OUTPUT -o eth1 -j DROP`
you can drop all outgoing traffic on interface eth1.
You'll probably also want to drop all forwarded traffic using `iptables -A FORWARD -o eth1 -j DROP`.

Comment: Info for the difference between `OUTPUT` and `FORWARD` here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/96548/what-is-the-difference-between-output-and-forward-chains-in-iptables

Answer (score 4):

To drop all the outgoing traffic on eth1

`iptables -I OUTPUT -o eth1 -j DROP`

will insert a rule at the begining of the OUTPUT chain to drop all outgoing traffic.

Comment: Thanks. Both were what I was looking for (no current rules so append or insert is fine) - but I've given it to kenny.r for being first.